# Rename Selected Cells Within Pandas String Vector

Tags: python, string, pandas, vector

I am simply trying to rename some of the cells within the 'location' column in a pandas dataframe.

The beginning of the dataframe looks like this:

```
Apr 25                   ASHEVILLE
Apr 25                   ASHEVILLE
Apr 25                   ASHEVILLE
Apr 25                   ASHEVILLE
Apr 25                   ASHEVILLE
Apr 25                   ASHEVILLE
Apr 25                   ASHEVILLE
Apr 25                   ASHEVILLE
Apr 25                   ASHEVILLE
Apr 25                   ASHEVILLE
Apr 25                   ASHEVILLE
Apr 25                   ASHEVILLE
Apr 25               ASHEVILLE N C
Apr 25               ASHEVILLE N C
Apr 25               ASHEVILLE N C
```

My best guess is:

```
postings.location = ["ASHEVILLE" for x in postings["location"] if "ASHEVILLE" in x]
```

but I get the following error message:

```
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

Comment: What you really want is to change the contents of the field if it is `ASHEVILLE `? It is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.loc` with .str accessor and `contains`:

```
postings.loc[postings.location.str.contains('ASHEVILLE'),'location'] = 'ASHEVILLE'
```